# How can I embed images using Nodemailer?

Tags: nodemailer

I'm trying to use nodemailer to send emails with embedded images.

It works and sends the email through as expected but the image doesn't appear?

My folder structure

```
mailer-prototype
  |-- node_modules
  |-- hero.jpg
  |-- index.js
```

index.js file

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
  port: 587,
  auth: {
    user: 'user@ethereal.email',
    pass: 'password123'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'user@ethereal.email',
  to: 'user@email.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!',
  html: '<h1>Welcome</h1><img src="cid:unique@nodemailer.com" alt="Test" />',
  attachments: [
    {
      filename: 'hero.jpg',
      path: __dirname+'/hero.jpg',
      cid: 'unique@nodemailer.com' 
    }
  ]
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

Is there something I'm missing?
I hope you can help, would be much appreciated.

Thanks All,
Moe

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue lies with ethereal's email platform on browser.

What I expect works as intended when I run the same code with:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
  secureConnection: false,
  port: 587,
  auth: {
    user: 'user@hotmail.com',
    pass: 'password123'
  }
});
```

I'm not entirely sure why but there you go.

Hope it helps anyone else.